# How do I print a back slash?

Tags: java, syntax

When I try `System.out.println("\\\\");`, it prints two back slashes, I only want to print one.

Comment: It seems like there's a fairly obvious candidate that you didn't try.

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println("\\");`. Backslash is the 'escape' character: you write one backslash, and then one other character which together represents a single character (the string length would be 1); a character that is hard to write normally.

`"\n"` has length 1 and is a newline character.

`"\\"` has length 1 and is one single backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the picture.  You use `"\\\\"` when you want to match a literal backslash in a Java regex / `Pattern`.  You need to escape once for the regex, and then both backslashes need to be escaped again ... because it is a String literal.

In short:

- `"\\"` for a literal backslash in a string literal
- `"\\\\"` to match a literal backslash in a regex expressed as a string literal

(It all makes sense if you think about it carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
\\
```

Example can be seen here:

```
System.out.println("\\");
```

Which produces:

```
\
```